# How to get Century Gothic font-size to be exactly 11pt?

Tags: vba, outlook

The standard font in our company emails is Century Gothic 11pt.

- If I use 11pt as per below, it gives me 10pt in the email.
- If I use 15px which is supposed to equate to 11pt, I get 11.5pt.

We are using **Office 365 Professional**.

```vb
With OutMail
    .Display
    .To = "a@b.com"
    .Subject = "Test Email"
    .HTMLBody = "<div style='font-family: ""Century Gothic"" ; font-size: 11pt;'>" & _
      "Hi All," & _
      "<p>This is a test email</p>" & _
      "Cheers,</div>" & _
      .HTMLBody ' appending the existing .HTMLBody which contains my signature
End With
```